# proof for existence of primitive roots mod prime p using $\sum_{d \mid p-1} \varphi(d)$ and $\sum_{d \mid p-1} \psi(d)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Im reading Number Theory by Andrej Dujella and I'm having a hard time understanding the proof that there are exactly $\varphi(d)$ numbers of order d mod p (p is prime). Here's the proof

---

Each of the numbers $1,2,3, ..., p-1$ belong to some exponent d modulo p, which is a divisor of $\varphi(p)=p-1$. We denote by $\psi(d)$ the number of elements in the sequence $1,2,...,p-1$ which belong to the exponent d. Then $$\sum_{d \mid p-1} \psi(d) = p-1.$$ It is sufficient to prove that if $\psi(d)\neq 0$,then $\psi(d) =\varphi(d)$, Indeed we have $$\sum_{d \mid p-1} \varphi(d)=p-1,$$ so if $\psi(d) =0 < \varphi(d)$ for some d, then the sum $\sum_{d \mid p-1} \psi(d)$ would be less than p-1. Hence, $\psi(d)\neq 0$ for every d.

Let us now prove the statement that $\psi(d) \neq 0$ implies $\psi(d) = \varphi(d)$. Let $\psi(d) \neq 0$ and let $a$ be a number belonging to the exponent $d$ modulo p. Consider the congruence $$x^d\equiv 1\mod p.$$ It has solutions $a, a^2, a^3, ..., a^d$, and by Lagrange's theorem, these are all solutions. Let us show that the numbers $a^m$, for $1\leq m \leq d$ and $gcd(m,d) =1$, represent all numbers belonging to the exponent d modulo p. Indeed, each of them has order d, because if $a^{md'} \equiv 1 \pmod p$, then $d\mid md'$, so $d\mid d'$. If $b$ is any number belonging to the exponent d modulo p, then $b\equiv a^m$ for some $m, 1\leq m\leq d$. Since $$b^{\frac{d}{gcd(m,d)}} \equiv (a^d)^{\frac{m}{gcd(m,d)}}\equiv 1 \pmod p,$$ we have $gcd(m,d) =1$. Hence, we proved that $\psi(d) = \varphi(d).$

---

The specific part I don't understand is how the proof proves there is at least 1 number of order d for each $d\mid p-1$

"we have $$\sum_{d \mid p-1} \varphi(d)=p-1,$$ so if $\psi(d) =0 < \varphi(d)$ for some d, then the sum $\sum_{d \mid p-1} \psi(d)$ would be less than p-1. Hence, $\psi(d)\neq 0$ for every d."

It seems that the contradiction the proof arrived at is wrong since it does not necessarily mean that $\psi(d)\neq 0$ for all $d$ since there is still room for $\psi(d) =0$ as long as $\sum_{d \mid p-1} \psi(d)$ remains p-1.

Can anyone clarity this for me, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said "since there is still room for $\psi(d) =0$ as long as $\sum_{d \mid p-1} \psi(d)$ remains p-1."

How will $\sum_{d \mid p-1} \psi(d)$ remain $p-1$?

It has been proved that $\psi(d) \le \varphi(d)$ for each $d$.

If at least one $\psi(d)=0$ you'll get $\psi(d) < \varphi(d)$ for that divisor $d$.

If you sum several non-strict inequalities with at least one strict inequality you get an strict inequality.

So $p-1 =\sum_{d\mid p-1} \psi(d) < \sum_{d\mid p-1} \varphi(d) = p-1$, a contradiction.